How do I prove that this is not regular L = $\{ a^i b^j c^k \mid k = i \times j \text{ and } 0 < i < 10 < j \}$
I made a CFG to prove that it's context-free, however, I wasn't able to convert it to left-linear or right-linear grammar.
\begin{align*}
S &\to \text{a}^iB \\
B &\to b^{11}Dc^{11\text{x}i}\\
D &\to bDc^i\mid \lambda
\end{align*}
So I want to prove that it's not regular using the pumping lemma, however, I'm a bit confused as what to do with the bound 0 < i < 10 < j
do I just choose a random value of i and have a string like:
$\{ a^2 b^m c^{2m} \}$
and prove it from there?
Also which part would be pumped, a's or b's or ab's, or are those all cases that I should consider?

You should use an extended version of the pumping lemma (see here), which has basically the same proof as the usual one.
Using that, assuming the language is regular with $m$ the pumping length, with $u = a^2$ and $v = c^{2m}$, $a^2b^mc^{2m} = uxyzv$ and:

$|xy| \leqslant m$;
$y \neq \varepsilon$;
$uxy^*zv\subseteq L$.

Since $y$ is composed of only $b$'s, you should find the contradiction.

are we supposed to use an arbitrary variable for a?
Also is this different from the CF pumping lemma because we are only pumping y?

This is the regular pumping lemma, just another version. I don't understand what you mean with "arbitrary variable for a".

because the language has ${a^i |0<i<10}$ it's not just a^2

That doesn't matter: in the word $a^2b^mc^{2m}$, the part you are doing the pumping is $b^m$, so the $a$'s do not matter.

Assume you have a finite state machine.
After parsing ab you are in a state where adding c, bc^2, b^2c^3 etc end in an accepting state.
After parsing abb you are in a state where adding c^2, bc^3 etc ends in an accepting state, so you are in a different state.
Show that after parsing ab^m every m leads to a different state. So you have no finite state machine.

You forgot 10<j. None of your explicitly mentioned cases are accepting.
